# What's the Powershell cmdlet to delete an endpoint created with New-SqlHadrEndPoint?

Tags: powershell, endpoint, high-availability

I have created an endpoint using New-SqlHadrEndpoint.

When I run the script it gives

```
New-SqlHadrEndpoint : Specified value 'endpoint01' already exists.
```

What is the cmdlet that I should run to delete it?

delete-SqlHadrEndpoint, remove-SqlHadrEndpoint and drop-SqlHadrEndpoint do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an endpoint to test, but the sqlps provider has an EndPoints container. I wonder if  the psprovider remove-item cmdlet would work?

```
SQLSERVER:SQL\NODE1\DEFAULT\Endpoints>dir
```